# Edit a msi database table

Tags: c#, msbuild, installation, wix, windows-installer

how can i add or delete entry of a  msi database table using msidb.exe rather than using the orca.Is there any commandline like below

```
msidb.exe [msipath][importingFilepath]
```

Once the file is added the corresponding entries in the msi tables should be updated

Thanks,

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the purpose of this? If you author your installation project in WiX (as the question tag states), then you must be doing something very wrong if you need manual injection...

Comment: Hi  Yan Sklyarenko,
Am a novice in the field of  windows installer.it will so grateful if you help me. 
No i don't need manual injection.I want to automate the process.Is there any tools to do these process

Comment: If you go after WiX, start with this tutorial: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial. That's the best getting started guideline I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although tools such as [msidb.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/2eee535f-e7f6-4e1a-9667-df4b8067b132) are capable of exporting and importing [text archive files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/49210242-bd32-4e5c-b782-a132d670fdfe), text archive files should only be used for the following specific purposes.

- Text archive files can be used with version control systems.
- To remove wasted storage space and reduce the final size of .msi
  files.
- To add localization information to an installation database.
- To determine the code page of a database.
- To set the code page of a database.
- To increase the limit of a database column. Authors cannot change the
  column data types, nullability, or localization attributes of any
  columns in standard tables.

A text archive file for a Windows Installer database carries an .idt file name extension and is in the [Archive File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/91d81fb2-3a41-477a-85c2-e68bfe482b9c).

You should use a Windows Installer table editing tool, such as Orca or a third-party tool, to create and modify an installation package.

Comment: hi thank you mark for your valuable information.Is there any other way to edit an msi database table with msidb.exe

Comment: It uses [MsiDatabaseImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/df277641-393e-4202-bb92-4b813ddaa0ca) & [MsiDatabaseExport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/c20c168d-900e-496a-894c-5678f308cdbe) under. See: [Windows Installer Development Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa372834(v=vs.85).aspx)  [WiImport.vbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/37580bd6-30c7-4239-9717-223a381ba021) & [WiExport.vbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/3ff7bd48-cb22-4d5b-a607-39eaeb67c55b)

Comment: yes mark i tried with that,The msi export you specified above will create all tables in .idt format.This .idt files are unordered and it will be difficult to parse and edit these files programmatically

Answer (score 6):

I'll assume you want to do this in C# since you included the C# tag.  WiX has a component called Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF - you'll find and SDK chm in the start menu ) that provides an excellent MSI interop.

Consider this:

```
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using( var database = new Database(@"C:\test.msi", DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That gives you the starting point to do anything you want to the database via SQL queries.

Comment: The Database class has Export/ExportAll and Import/ImportAll methods in case you decide to convert it to text,  search and replace the strings and reimport without the use of SQL queries.